# Move all files of same type in multiple directories up one folder

Tags: file, unix, command-line

I have about 2000 subfolders in one folder, in each of these folders there are `.pdf` files. I need a unix command that will move all these files up one folder.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
$ cd thefolder # which contains the subfolders and where the PDFs should land
$ find . -name *.pdf | xargs -I {} cp -iv {} .

# find all files
# which end in .pdf
# recursively from
# the current folder
#                    |
#                      for each emitted line
#                      copy the output (captured by {}) to 
#                      the specified path ('.' is the current directory)
#                      copy should be verbose and should ask,
#                      in case a file would be overwritten
```

This should copy your files into `/thefolder/`. If you want to move them replace `cp` with `mv`.

Comment: Thanks, but I need to know that this will work for sure, I cannot lose/misplace any of these files, and don't have much knowledge in this area...

Comment: This works if I go into each subfolder and run the command, but I'm looking for something that will look in each subdirectory then move the files up, a command I wouldn't have to run multiple times in each folder.

Comment: @sassy_geekette: `|` is a pipe, connecting two programs via their input and output. So to test, just execute `find . -name *.pdf` alone (this won't copy or move anything). If this matches the files you are interested in, the do the following: `find . -name *.pdf | xargs -I {} echo {}`. The output should be the same. Still, this won't move or copy anything. Then `cp` or `mv`.