# Move only mp3s within multiple directories to a single folder

Tags: macos, bash, mp3, cp

This [solution from SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3686860/move-all-files-of-same-type-in-multiple-directories-up-one-folder) works but unfortunately some of my mp3s have quotes (') in their names which results in the following error:

```
xargs: unterminated quote
```

Is it possible to adapt the following command to allow it to copy all mp3s, regardless of the quotes in their file name?

```
find . -name "*.mp3" | xargs -I {} cp -iv "{}" /my/dir
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
find . -name "*.mp3" -exec cp -iv {} /my/dir \;
```

Answer (score 4):

Try adding `-print0` to `find` and `-0` to `xargs`.